# Why do constraints 0 0 0 0 not fit the whole view?

Tags: ios

EXAMPLE 1

I am using Xcode 8.2 beta and when I try to make view fits the whole screen it does not include the section where battery icon at .

[image]
[image]

update the frames and then

[image]

EXAMPLE 2

When I try to cover whole view first  and then set constraints 0 0 0 0  it fits the whole screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In both example I set constraints 0 0 0 0  but different results. Why ?
Can somebody explain please ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up constraints with the controller's top layout guide, instead of the view itself. The top layout guide is influenced by things, such as status bar, navigation bar, etc. That is why you are seeing two different results.

Comment: Thank you so much ! In real app development, which one do I need to prefer ? I am a newbie. Top layout guide or view itself ?

Comment: Both are viable for whatever you want to do. If you want your content to reach the whole view, you'd prefer to constraint against the view itself, while usually, more prominent UI elements, such as buttons, you would normally want to constraint against the layout guides and margins.